# Get only just id from URL

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

searched and could not find exact solution for following issue. Namely, i have a lot of URLs which looks like:

```
https://{domain name}/{type of data}/4583236-{name-of-perpetrators}
```

My task is to pickup ID from url above. Tried this without success:

```
dataPosted.get(l).getAttribute("data-user-id");
```

Above get(l) is from counter, and below is HTML for that particular URL:

```
<div class="list-box-user-action">
 <span><a href="https://{domain name}/{type of data}/4583236-{name-of-perpetrators}" class="">Title</a></span>
```

Also here is screenshot from page source

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the ID in this URL?

Comment: plz provide bit more information

Comment: @Henry ID is number in URL https://{domain name}/{type of data}/4583236-{name-of-perpetrators} (here is 45832360

Comment: And what is {type of data}? In particular, can it be that '/' characters are in it?

Comment: @Henry yes, indeed

Comment: `href` of that `a` element is `#`. It doesn't look like your URL pattern. Where do you get `<a href="https://{domain name}/{type of data}/4583236-{name-of-perpetrators}" class="">Title</a>` from?

Comment: @Buaban - it is, copied from page source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to need to extract the `String` either from the `URL` or from the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag as follows :

- Extract the `String` **`https://{domain name}/{type of data}/4583236-{name-of-perpetrators}`** from the `URL` :

  ```
  String my_href = driver.getCurrentUrl();
  ```
- Extract the `String` **`https://{domain name}/{type of data}/4583236-{name-of-perpetrators}`** from the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag :

  ```
  String my_href = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='list-box-user-action']/span/a[contains(.,'Title')]"));
  ```
- Now you can split the `String` **`https://{domain name}/{type of data}/4583236-{name-of-perpetrators}`** to extract **`4583236`** :

  ```
  String[] urlParts = my_href.split(Pattern.quote("{type of data}/"));
  String mySuburl = urlParts[1];
  String[] suburl = mySuburl.split(Pattern.quote("-{name-of-perpetrators}"));
  String mytext = suburl[0];
  System.out.println(mytext);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with following RegEx:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(link);
String g = m.group();
```